# passing post data from view to controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

i have a strange problem.

in my codeigniter project i have a form ( in a view) and a controller.
the data from the form is being past as a post data. but in my controller i can not show the data.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/activiteit/saveNew" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Titel:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="title"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Datum:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Korte beschrijving:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="short"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Lange beschrijving:</div>
    <textarea class="col-md-9" type="text" name="long"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 spatie"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 btn btn-info" value="Opslaan"/>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
public function saveNew()
{   
    if(isset($_POST))
    {   
        //$acti = new Activiteiten();

        echo "test1: " +  $this->input->post('title');
        echo $this->input->post('date');
        echo $this->input->post('short');
        echo $this->input->post('long');

        /*
        $acti->title = $this->input->post('title');
        $acti->date = $this->input->post('date');
        $acti->short = $this->input->post('short');
        $acti->long = $this->input->post('long');
        $acti->save();
        $acti->save_as_new();
        */ 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'no post
    }
}
```

if i check the post data in firebug i do get the post data but in the html it shows '0'

can anybody help me?

Comment: is it showing '0'?or "no post"?

Comment: How come this code shows 0?either it will show "no post" or it will show something start with "test1: ". Check you are at right function or you have somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

its the + sign, it needs to be a period to concatenate

change this

```
 echo "test1: " +  $this->input->post('title');
```

to this

```
 echo "test1: " . $this->input->post('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more Google work, i found probably found a solution. the problem could be in my .htacces file.

this is my .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|assets/bootstrap/|assets/CSS/|assets/font/|assets/font-awesome/|assets/img/|assets/javascript/|assets/JQuery/|cms/|cms/bootstrap/|cms/CSS/|cms/font-awesome/|cms/img/|cms/javascript/|cms/JQuery/|public/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but i don't get all of it.

my controller is placed at this path:
  applications/controllers/cms/activiteit.php
the views are placed at this path:
  applications/views/cms/activiteit_add.php

can anybody explain whats wrong with my htacces file!